# Nested stack navigator header configuration

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I've two stack navigator that the second stack is nested in the second :

```
export default createStackNavigator( //Settings navigator
    {
        HomeSettings: SettingsScreen
    },
    {
        headerLayoutPreset: "center",
        headerMode: "none"
    }
);

export default createStackNavigator( //Main navigator
    {
        HomeProfile: ProfileScreen,
        Prescriptions: PrescriptionsScreen,
        PrescriptionDetails: PrescriptionDetailsScreen,
        Settings: SettingsNavigator
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "HomeProfile",
        headerLayoutPreset: "center",
        headerMode: "screen"
    })
```

From a screen from my children navigator, I can't set a title in the header using :

```
SettingsScreen.navigationOptions = {
    headerTitle: "My custom header"
}
```

(nothing appends)

What is the best pattern to do that ? Note that I want to keep the header back button to go back from my Settings navigator to the main navigator.

Comment: ```headerMode```  - Specifies how the header should be rendered. ```none``` - No header will be rendered. Could the problem be in ```headerMode: "none"``` parameter?

Comment: If I remove, I'll have two header nested... The header from the main navigator, and the header from the children navigator, I would like that my children header inherit from his parent.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `navigationOptions` on `SettingsScreen` only affects the options of the navigator it is in, i.e. `SettingsNavigator`. But you want to change the title in parent navigator (`MainNavigator`). You need to do:

```js
SettingsNavigator,navigationOptions = {
  // ...
}
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html